# Find sub directories where a string is not present in one of the files

Tags: bash

I have a directory with lot of subdirectories in `Linux`.

Each subdirectories contains a file called `variables_list.txt`

Now in each `variables_list.txt` file I want to check if a string is present or not.

For example:

if the string is like below

```
export host_name=
```

I want to find out all the subdirectories where in the `variables_list.txt` file the string is not present.

I tried like below

```
grep -r -l "export host_name=" .
```

This is printing all the file names where the string is present.

I tried like below as well

```
grep -Hrn "export host_name="
```

This also prints all the file names where the string is present with the line number

I can I achieve what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe grep results to `dirname`:

```
grep -v -Z -r -l "export host_name=" .  | xargs -0 dirname
```

Example:

```
$ mkdir {1..10}
$ mkdir 'test dir with space'
$ echo export host_name= >> 2/variables_list.txt
$ echo export host_name= > 3/variables_list.txt
$ echo export host_name= > 4/variables_list.txt
$ echo export host_name= > 5/variables_list.txt
$ echo export host_nname= > 'test dir with space'/variables_list.txt
$ echo export hostt_name= > 3/variables_list.txt
$ find . -name variables_list.txt -exec sh -c 'grep "export host_name=" "$1" >/dev/null || echo "$(dirname "$1")"' sh {} \;
./3
./test dir with space
```

Comment: When I am trying the grep command you have given I am getting all the files in the directories. I just want to find the directory names where in the `variables_list.txt` file the string is not present.

Comment: You don't get the filenames, you get directory names. If my example doesn't reflect your setup tell me what's wrong and I'll change it.

Comment: What I want is to check only the `variables_list.txt` file in each directory and if the string is not present in the `variables_list.txt` file then only print the directory name. I don't want to check other files in the directory.

Comment: Perfect! This is what i was looking for